# How HTTP PUT should work

Tags: http, rest, put

For example, there is resource on URI: `/api/items/123`

Response body for GET request is `{"Id": "123", "Foo": "foo", "Bar": "bar"}`

I send PUT request. The body of it is `{"Bar": "newBarValue"}`

In case of this request body, should properties **Id** and **Foo** be removed? Or just **Bar** property should be modified? Or server should return error code?

Comment: You would like to read [this post](http://www.kreuzwerker.de/blog/edge-cases-of-updates-in-restful-json-apis/).

Comment: Nice article! thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PUT and GET should use the full resource.

If you just want to update the resource (and just send Bar) then you can also use the PATCH http verb.

A list of restful verbs:
https://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `PUT` should provide the *complete* new representation of the resource. So `Id` and `Foo` should be removed on the server.

If you just want to *update* `Bar`, `POST` `{"Bar": "newBarValue"}` to it.

As often in REST, this is only a convention.